What is the corresponding lambda-calculus / proof terms of intuitionistic first order logic? (looking for references)
It is an oft-repeated result that lambda calculi correspond to logics. In particular, recall the following (approximate) relationships

intuitionistic propositional logic ⇄ simply typed lambda calculus
intuitionistic second order logic (without first order quantification) ⇄ System F

My general question is: what is the corresponding lambda calculus to intuitionistic first order logic?
The key missing feature is terms for the quantification over objects from a universe of individuals. Thus we can solve the general question by just taking the STLC and adding terms that introduce and eliminate such quantifiers.
However, what I'm really after is papers/results developing this calculus and its theory. I feel like I've seen such a paper in the past, but I can't find it now.
Thus, my specific questions are the following: what is the lambda calculus corresponding to IFOL? Is there any interesting theory about it? Are there any papers about it? How does it interact with the lambda cube?
P.S. I also note that this question has been asked before in the question What order logic does a system correspond to under Curry–Howard correspondence?, but I find the answer unsatisfying, as it's just speculation.

From what I could find there's this.

Intuitionistic first-order logic corresponds to dependent types: propositions quantify over elements ∀(x : A), P where x may occur in P (in other words, "the type P depends on x"). This is the system called λP in the lambda cube.
(In comparison, proof assistants such as Coq, Agda, and Lean implement the calculus of construction, aka. λC in the lambda cube, which generalizes F and λP in that it allows quantification over both elements and types.)
A good reference is An introduction to generalized type systems by Barendregt (1991). λP is defined  as a special case of a Generalized Type System on pages 6-7 (pages 129-130 in print). PRED (intuitionistic first-order logic, aka. predicate logic) is defined on page 18, and a sound and complete translation from PRED to λP is given. Soundness is Corollary 4.14 (page 24) (if a first-order formula is provable, then its translation in λP is inhabited). Completeness (the converse), more challenging, is mentioned on page 17, citing Martin-Löf (1970): A Construction of the Provable Wellorderings of the Theory of Species. That same paragraph also mentions that completeness does not hold everywhere on the lambda cube, namely it fails between λC and the corresponding logic in the L-cube. In short, there are plenty of subtleties in trying to make sense of "proposition as types" as an equivalence.
